# Find constructor of array element class

Tags: typescript

I have a basic method:

```
function foo<T>(data:any, clazz:new(...args:any[])=>T):T{
    //Example impl, just to demonstrate the issue
    if(data instanceof Array){
        return new clazz();
    }
    return [new clazz()];
}
```

So, I want it to work with both object and arrays, like this:

```
let bar:Bar = foo<Bar>(Bar); //Works fine actually
let bars:Bar[] = foo<Bar[]>(Bar); //Should return a Bar[]
```

It doesn't work because `Bar` is not the constructor for `Bar[]`.

I already tried with:

```
foo<Bar[]>(Bar[])
foo<Bar[]>(Array<Bar>)
foo<Array<Bar>>(Array<Bar>)
```

Comment: You'd better have to different signatures - generic type parameter is not available at runtime, so there's no way to know if consumer asked an array or a single instance

Comment: The main goal of the question is to find a way to do this with only one signature, doing it with two signatures is easier but it requires the end-user of the function to call another method for arrays, that's not very dev-friendly :/

Comment: I don't understand the array part. Regardless of the type, you always need to return `[]`.

Comment: Yes but this is an example implementation, the final one will add class instances in the array with data inside it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I changed the example implementation to add more details for the array part.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your use case, but it's not easy based on the code you posted. What is this `data`? Is it something that is used to instantiate the objects? I understand that the code you posted is aimed to simplify things, but maybe, in this case, it also doesn't convey what your problem is.

Comment: The use case is a deserializer that adds type and prototype to objects, the main goal being that only one method will be able to handle both objects and arrays. If too many users of the library ask for a specific array method we'll do it, but at the moment we want to handle everything with the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with signature overloading and based on passed parameter decide to return array or a single instance:

```
type Constructor<T> = new () => T;

function foo<T>(clazz: [Constructor<T>]): T[]
function foo<T>(clazz: Constructor<T>): T
function foo<T>(clazz: Constructor<T> | [Constructor<T>]) {
    if(clazz instanceof Array){
        return [new clazz[0]];
    }
    return new clazz();
}

let arrayResult = foo([Bar]);
let result = foo(Bar);
```

Comment: Oh, I like that better than my `ArrayOf` stuff.

Comment: Your solution is fine but a problem persists: how can I ensure that the dev won't provide [Bar, Bar]? I mean it would be useless anyways but... Still good to know if it's possible to forbid that.

Comment: @Supamiu, as a workaround you can define a function as `function foo<T>(clazz: [Constructor<T>] & { 1?: void})`. But I think this worth another question with more details (what exactly you want to forbid, as fixed length tuples are not currently supported)

Answer (score 1):

What you asked for, namely:

```
let bar:Bar = foo<Bar>(Bar); //Works fine actually
let bars:Bar[] = foo<Bar[]>(Bar); //Should return a Bar[]
```

can never work, since types are erased at runtime. The JavaScript for both will look like:

```
let bar = foo(Bar);
let bars = foo(Bar);
```

so there's no way to tell the difference.

As @AlekseyL suggests, the most straightforward solution is to have two functions to handle the array/non-array cases.  If you *really* want one function, we need to have a way to let it know at runtime what to do.

First, let's create the helper `Constructor` type, since I hate writing out that `new(...` stuff all the time:

```
type Constructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Now let's create an `ArrayOf` type which is just an object holding the relevant class constructor.  We also need a type guard to detect if something is an `ArrayOf` at runtime, and a function to make an `ArrayOf` that devs can use:

```
type ArrayOf<T> = {
  clazz: Constructor<T>;
}
function isArrayOf<T>(x: Constructor<T> | ArrayOf<T>): x is ArrayOf<T> {
  return 'clazz' in x;
}
function ArrayOf<T>(clazz: Constructor<T>): ArrayOf<T> {
  return { clazz };
}
```

Finally we can implement `foo()`:

```
function foo<T>(clazz: Constructor<T>): T;
function foo<T>(arrayOfClazz: ArrayOf<T>): T[];
function foo<T>(x: Constructor<T> | ArrayOf<T>): T | T[] {
  if (isArrayOf(x)) {
    return [new x.clazz()];
  } else {
    return new x();
  }
}
```

It's an overloaded function that either takes a constructor, or an `ArrayOf` object, and then determines what to do at runtime. Let's make sure it works:

```
class Bar {
  // ... 
}

const bar: Bar = foo(Bar);
const bars: Bar[] = foo(ArrayOf(Bar));
```

There you go; it works!

---

But that's fairly complicated compared to just having two functions.  For the developer, all of these would be about the same amount of effort:

```
  // what you wanted
  let bar = foo<Bar>(Bar); 
  let bars = foo<Bar[]>(Bar);  // will not work, as above 

  // what I gave you
  let bar = foo(Bar);
  let bars = foo(ArrayOf(Bar));

  // two functions
  let bar = foo(Bar);
  let bars = fooArray(Bar);
```

I think the two-function solution is probably the most dev-friendly, but that's just my opinion.  Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

#### Update

Ugh, I see you edited your code to add a new `data` parameter to `foo`, which is either an array or not, and you want to return an array or not based on that.  In this case, the solution is fairly straightforward:

```
function foo<T>(data: any[], clazz: Constructor<T>): T[];
function foo<T>(data: any, clazz: Constructor<T>): T;
function foo<T>(data: any, clazz: Constructor<T>): T | T[] {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return [new clazz()];
  } else {
    return new clazz();
  }
}

const bar: Bar = foo('bar',Bar);
const bars: Bar[] = foo(['bars'], Bar);
```

Good luck again.